# Django include - using the correct include depending on the page

Tags: django, include, block

Hi guys I am fairly new to the Django framework and was hoping someone could assist me in my current dilemma :)

I have my base template set up for my project. I have a `main-content` area and a `side-bar`

I created a include for my `side bar`:

```
{% include "modules/include/sidebar.html" %}
```

The issue is that I have two different side bars that I would like to render depending on the page the user is on e.g. if the user is on the home page then use

```
{% include "modules/include/sidebar.html" %}
```

but if the user is on an article page then use

```
{% include "modules/include/article-sidebar.html" %}
```

I looked through the docs but couldn't find anything to help me solve this issue.

All and any help will be appreciate.

Comment: Surely just put the relevant `include` statement in the relevant HTML file?

Comment: @gtlambert the include is placed in one file which is the base.html template

Answer (score 1):

Create a block in your base template, something like `{% block sidebar %}{% endblock %}`

Then in your home page template do

```
{% extends 'your-base-template-name-here' %}

{% block sidebar %}
     {% include "modules/include/sidebar.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

And in your article template use

```
{% extends 'your-base-template-name-here' %}

{% block sidebar %}
     {% include "modules/include/article-sidebar.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

More about template inheritance here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/language/#id1